# Value of array in structure still changing

Tags: c, arrays, structure

I have a problem. I written the some values to my array and i want to send handle to inicialize frame to connecting with my device, but when i pick up the structure my data from struct overvrite the another value than i want.

**There are my foo:**

```
int handlePackets (struct _PacketData * outputPacket, uint8_t command){
    outputPacket->addr = SERIAL;
    outputPacket->length = 0;
    outputPacket->cmd = command;

    switch (outputPacket->cmd)
    {
        case CMD_SET_OUTPUT:
            outputPacket->length = 0x06;

            outputPacket->data[0] = 0x80;
            outputPacket->data[1] = 0x3F;
            outputPacket->data[2] = 0x10;
            outputPacket->data[3] = 0x40;
            outputPacket->data[4] = 0x30;
            return COMM_FRAME_OK;
    }
    return COMM_FRAME_OK;
}
int sendPacket (struct _PacketData * outputPacket, uint8_t * buffer){
int cntr = 0, x;

buffer[cntr++] = STX;
buffer[cntr++] = outputPacket->addr >> 24;
buffer[cntr++] = outputPacket->addr >> 16;
buffer[cntr++] = outputPacket->addr >> 8;
buffer[cntr++] = outputPacket->addr & 0xff;

buffer[cntr++] = outputPacket->length >> 8;             
buffer[cntr++] = outputPacket->length & 0xff;

buffer[cntr++] = outputPacket->cmd;

for (x = 0; x < outputPacket->length -1 ; x++)
{
    buffer[cntr++] = outputPacket->data[x];     
}
crc = calcCrcBuffer (buffer + 1, cntr - 1);

buffer[cntr++] = (unsigned char) (crc >> 8);        //crc high byte
buffer[cntr++] = (unsigned char) (crc & 0xff);      //crc low byte

buffer[cntr++] = ETX;
return cntr;
}
```

**structure**

```
struct _PacketData{
uint32_t addr;
uint16_t length;
uint8_t cmd;
uint8_t data[256];};
```

**main.c**

```
int main(void) {
struct _PacketData  * outputOutPack;

uint8_t tab[256];
int i;

    uint8_t *buffer = tab;

  handlePackets(&outputOutPack,CMD_SET_OUTPUT );

  result = sendPacket(&outputOutPack, buffer);}
```

The output of my frame is not like i need. Data overvrite the values from buffer[cntr] but i dont know why.

**Output:**

```
[0] = 0x82
[1] = 00
[2] = 0x18
[3] = 0xb0
[4] = 0xa5
[5] = 00
[6] = 0x6
[7] = 0x78
[8] = 0x82
[9] = 00
[10] = 0x18
[11] = 0xb0
[12] = 0xa5
[13] = 0x64
[14] = 0xfe
[15] = 0x83
```

Position 7 is output->cmd and next is output->data, [8-12], but its not my array :)

Any suggestion?

Thanks

Comment: your functions takes a pointer to the struct not pointer to a pointer can you change `struct _PacketData  * outputOutPack;` to `struct _PacketData   outputOutPack;`

Comment: Turn on your compiler's warnings. The compiler should complain about wrong data type for parameter #1 of handlePackets and sendPacket.

Comment: It works! One symbol and 2 days lost on finding fault. It was my oversight, but sometimes another person will see where is problem. Thanks a lot cmidi!

Comment: @cvanyy you can accept the answer if it does

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you compile the code you would see the following warnings.

```
warning: passing argument 1 of 'handlePackets' from incompatible pointer type
note: expected 'struct _PacketData *' but argument is of type 'struct _PacketData **'
```

The reason for the problem is that your functions(`handlePackets` and `sendPacket`) takes a pointer to the `struct _PacketData` not pointer to a pointer.
You need to change struct `_PacketData * outputOutPack;` to `struct _PacketData outputOutPack;`

What you are essentially doing when you provide the functions with a pointer to a pointer, is dereferencing the memory you allocated to the pointer type on the stack this leads to undefined behavior and potentially corrupting your stack.